# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') Hardhat

Tags: solidity, ether, ethers.js, hardhat, ethereumjs

when i try to run this code use `npx hardhat test` in terminal

give me output

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

this is my code file Escrow.js

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

const tokens = (n) => {
  return ethers.utils.parseUnits(n.toString(), "ether");
};

describe("Escrow", () => {
  it('saves the addresses', async () => {

    const signers = await ethers.getSigners()
    console.log(signers)

    // Deploy Real Estate
    const realEstate = new ethers.Contract("RealEstate");
    realEstate = await RealEstate.deploy();

    console.log(realEstate.address)

    // Mint
    let transaction = await realEstate.mint(
      "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmQVcpsjrA6cr1iJjZAodYwmPekYgbnXGo4DFubJiLc2EB/1.json"
    );
  });
});
```

this is my code file Escrow.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

interface IERC721 {
    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _id
    ) external;
}

contract Escrow {
    address public nftAddress;
    address payable public seller;
    address public lender;
    address public inspector;

    constructor(
        address _nftAddress,
        address payable _seller,
        address _inspector,
        address _lender
    ) {
        nftAddress = _nftAddress;
        seller = _seller;
        inspector = _inspector;
        lender = _lender;
    }

}
```

and this is my code RealEstate.sol

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.7.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import {ERC721} from "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";

contract RealEstate is ERC721URIStorage{
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;

    constructor() ERC721("Real Estate", "REAL") {}

    function mint(string memory tokenURI) public returns (uint256) {
        _tokenIds.increment();

        uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newItemId);
        _setTokenURI(newItemId, tokenURI);
        
        return newItemId;
    }

    function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
        return _tokenIds.current();
    }
}
```

Why does it happen? How can I make it work?

Comment: That error is quite generic, can you show more details about the error message?